# express session with connect-mongodb-session not getting cookies in browser but postman works well

Tags: mongodb, express, session

i am getting set-cookie in response header but my browser does not use it.
also, the cookie is not sent to the server there every time a new session is made on server side due to this.

I have checked my routes on postman everything working as expected i.e : cookies are receive and sent by postman but the browser completely ignores cookies.

[zip file of project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vb5rpyb5GF2mfkYB7lg9L8ewoUtfQVvi/view)

```
index.js
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const mongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session)

const routes = require('./routes/routes')

require('./model/model');
require('./db/mongoose')

const app = express();

const store = new mongoDBStore({
    uri: 'mongodb+srv://mny:QTCdKtdkjfdjfouJJWbUYN@cluster0.zxfwd.mongodb.net/MernDocker?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
    collection: "mySessions"
})

// app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(express.json());
// app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", 'true')//true as string
    // res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers',
    // 'Date, Etag, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Set-Cookie, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials')
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PATCH,POST,DELETE");
        return res.status(200).send()
    }
    next();
});

app.use(session({
    secret: "mny",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        path: "/",//if / the cookies will be sent for all paths
        httpOnly: false,// if true, the cookie cannot be accessed from within the client-side javascript code.
        secure: true,// true->cookie has to be sent over HTTPS
        maxAge: 2*24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        sameSite: 'none',//- `none` will set the `SameSite` attribute to `None` for an explicit cross-site cookie.
    },
    store: store,
    resave: false,
}))

app.use(routes);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen((port), (error) => {
    console.log(`lisning on port ${port}`)
})
```

```
const express = require('express');
const User = require('../model/model');

const routes = express.Router();

/*
routes.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('req.headers.cookie get')
    console.log(req.headers.cookie)
    // console.log(req.headers.cookie.split(';')[1].split('=')[1])
    res.send({
        "post": req.session.postClick,
        "patch": req.session.patchClick
    })
})*/

routes.post('/', async (req, res) => {

    console.log("req.headers.cookie post method")
    console.log(req.headers)

    // console.log(req.headers.cookie.split(';')[1])
    const user = new User(req.body)

    try {
        await user.save()
        if (!req.session.postClick) {
            req.session.postClick = 0
            console.log(req.session);
        }
        req.session.postClick++
        res.send({ "user": user, "postClick": req.session.postClick });
    } catch (e) {
        res.send(e)
    }
})

module.exports = routes;
```

```
app.js frontend

import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
const url = 'http://localhost:3001'
console.log(document.cookie)

function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({
    name: '',
  })

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setInputValue({
      ...inputValue,
      [name]: value
    })
  }

  const handleOnAdd = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(document.cookie)
    const addData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(`${url}`, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            "mode": 'cors',
            "Credentials": 'include',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'WithCredentials': true,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(inputValue)
        })
        if (res.ok) {
          let d = await res.json()
          console.log(d)
        } else {
          alert('fetch add failed')
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    }
    addData()
    // setInputValue({})
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>session with mongodb</h1>
      <form className='form' >
        <label>name</label>
        <input
          name='name'
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
          value={inputValue.name}
        />
        <button onClick={handleOnAdd}>Add</button>
      </form>

    </div>
  )

}

export default App;
```

Comment: The cookie attribute `secure: true` means that it is only set over https. However, you make requests to your backend http://localhost:3001 over http, not https.

Comment: you are right but I have tried this false also it had not worked.

finely I use one port for both backend and front end( similar to the deployment case of Heroku) in that way i have avoid any CORS error.